# Is it possible to use something like dropzone.js for file uploads with sprout forms?

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm trying to come up with a nice UI experience for people to upload a CV and covering letter and I'm considering using something like http://www.dropzonejs.com/

I'm not sure how this would work with sprout forms because you have to put a action in the form to make it work (from what I can tell anyways)

Is there a solution for this or is there an alternative approach you know that would work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to upload the files and index them as assets, then return the asset id's to your form. You can then use these asset id's in your form so you can post them to the server, effectively creating the relations you want.

I've put up a little gist that does this for jQuery File Upload - you can use it as a reference for any other upload mechanisms: https://gist.github.com/boboldehampsink/2e645655d613574ec4b7